# Ran chkdsk /F C:, now partition is RAW

Tags: chkdsk

I was trying to clone my system drive with Macrium software, and it would not complete saying there was a cyclical redundancy issue.

So I ran chkdsk (without /F) from the command prompt and noticed it said something about an invalid image. I don't recall the exact text.

Anyway, I ran chkdsk /F, it needed to restart in order to do it. After the restart it said "Checking drive C for errors". When it was done, the system won't boot. I get the blue screen with stop code NTFS File System.

My system drive is an SSD, and has 3 partitions. Extra ones I did not create, and are small (like 500Mb), I assume for recovery or something.

If I use a Windows 10 CD to boot, and try to repair it doesn't work. Further investigating via the command prompt available via the CD I ran the DIR command on C:. It shows an empty file system with about 500Mb of space, so that is obviously one of the extra partitions now being seen as the system partition.

So, any ideas what chkdsk screwed up, and how to fix it? How to get the partitions back as they were?

EDIT: Running Diskpart I see that the volume is shown as RAW for the file system. Any way to fix that without loosing the data?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> it would not complete saying there was a cyclical redundancy issue

Your disk is seemingly dying. The problem is that continuing to access it in this case may lead to even more damage. Hopefully you've got backups. If you have none,  at the moment your only option is to find a local service center where they can try to restore data.

Comment: Not dying. There is apparently an issue with running chkdsk /F on an SSD drive in Windows 10. I now have a "RAW" partition where the OS resides, so it cannot be accesssed.

https://www.tomshardware.com/news/chkdsk-windows-10-command-breaking-ssds

Comment: This issue has long been fixed and considering its prevalence I'm not sure it was valid in the first place. The article you've provided is almost a year old. *The company said in its December 8th updates that “This issue is resolved and should now be prevented automatically on non-managed devices.”*